# Helper function for boolean property to display "yes" or "no"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create my own helper function in ASP.NET MVC 3.  Not sure if I am on the correct path.  I have a boolean property called Active, when I display the property on the display view then the text is either "True" or "False".  So I thought of writing my own helper that accepts this boolean value and either returns "Yes" or "No".  Do I need a helper for this, or is there a shorter way?

This is what I currently have, it does not compile, can someone please help me here?  The accompanying unit test will be appreciated.

```
public static IHtmlString ConvertBooleanToYesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool value)
{
   string str = string.Empty;

   if (value)
   {
      return htmlHelper.Encode("Yes");
   }
   else
   {
      return htmlHelper.Encode("No");
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Error is:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.IHtmlString'**

I know I have to convert it, but was just wondering if this was the best way to do it?

Comment: Looks fine for me. Can you post the compilation error?

Comment: Answer below by Glenn should work fine for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HtmlHelper.Encode returns a String object not an IHtmlString.

Use `return new HtmlString("Yes");`

Or simply

```
public static IHtmlString ConvertBooleanToYesNo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool value) {
  return new HtmlString(value ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

The [HtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee360280.aspx) class will handle encoding for you but in the case of a simple 'Yes/No' string, no encoding is required.

Comment: you dont have to worry about that if the text contains no special characters

Comment: better yet, simplify the whole method to 1 line: return new HtmlString( value ? "Yes" : "No");

Comment: @Brendan: Looked up HtmlString to make sure: it's encoded already, as part of ToString override: "This method returns a human-readable string that is culture sensitive. The string is also HTML encoded.".

Comment: Encoding is only needed to ensure the string is safe to display as HTML. 'Yes' and 'No' do not require any encoding.  Regardless of this the HtmlString constructor will handle encoding for you anyway.